# Access Violation when assigning component property on Data Module

Tags: delphi, datamodule

I'm on Delphi 2009, and my application contains a data module, which has a custom component named 'Globals' on it.

In another form in the application, I'm trying to change a published property (a string) on the Globals component:

```
  dm.Globals.qhProject := _ProjectName.Text; //always gives access violation
```

The _ProjectName control is a TLabeledEdit descendant.  I always get an access violation here if there's any text in the box.

However, if I manually assing a string to the property, I don't get the AV:

```
  dm.Globals.qhProject := 'some text'; //works
```

Here's the declaration of the qhProject property:

```
FqhProject: string;    
property qhProject: string read FqhProject write FqhProject;
```

I can't figure out why there's an AV here at all.  I've tried moving the auto create order of the forms/data module around, but I always get the AV.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:**

I'm using Billenium Effects TFormContainer to switch between different forms in the application.  Both forms that are involved here are in the form container.  One form, TdlgSummary, contains the following:

```
procedure TdlgSummary.SyncVars;
begin
    dm.Globals.qhProject := _ProjectName.Text
end;
```

The other form, TdlgFinalize, contains the following:

```
dlgSummary.SyncVars;
```

If I run SyncVars inside of dlgSummary, it works fine.  If I call it from dlgFinalize, I get the AV.  This seems to be the crux of the problem, but I can't figure out what's going wrong.  Even if I switch control to dlgFinalize, dlgSummary hasn't been destroyed, because I can go back to it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like _ProjectName is **nil**.  Try putting a breakpoint at this line and examine _ProjectName, see if it gives a valid reference or not.

Comment: Several of these forms are inside a TFormContainer, which is part of the Billenium Effects component suite.

It gives a valid reference when the form containing the _ProjectName runs the above code.  When another forms runs it, the reference isn't valid.  Not sure where to go from here, since I can switch back and forth between the forms, and the form with the _ProjectName control hasn't been destroyed....

Comment: Further details:  It seems that I can't access the form with the labled edit (TdlgSummary) from another form.  I can't figure out why, though.

I have the source file in the uses statement, and I'm accessing it like the following:

dlgSummary._ProjectName.Text //throws an AV

Comment: I'm not familiar with Billenium Effects or form containers, but check to see if the form is being created by the form container and not by the DPR.  dlgSummary is a global variable declared in the form's unit, but if Delphi isn't initializing it at startup because the form container is supposed to, and the form container is just instantiating an instance of the form class and assigning it to an internal list and not to the designated global, than your global form variable will be left as a nil.  I'm firing blindly in the dark here, but see if that's what's going on...

Comment: That's it!  

The TFormContainer was creating the form, and wasn't assigned it to the global variable list.

Adding "dlgSummary := Self;" to TdlgSummary's OnCreate solved it.

Thanks so much for your help! Super answer....

Comment: Yep, that'll do it, as long as you only ever create one instance of TdlgSummary.  A safer way to do it, if the form container supports it, would be to not use the global for the form and instead use something along the lines of "FormContainer.FindFormByClass(TDlgSummary);" to obtain your reference.  Hopefully the form container has some trick like that to find a specific form...